# agnoster theme: time in color

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, colors, prompt

I'm using agnoster theme:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

and I was wondering how to color time in a different color of username.

At the moment, my prompt_context() function from agnoster.theme.sh file is like that:

```
prompt_context() {
local user=`whoami`

if [[ $user == $DEFAULT_USER || $user != $DEFAULT_USER || -n $SSH_CLIENT ]]; then
        # green is the color of background
        # white is the color of foreground
        
    prompt_segment green white "[\A] $user@\h "     
fi
```

}

The problem is the colors are the same for my username and for time.

I've already tried things like that:

```
prompt_segment green white " ${red green [\A]}$user@\h "
```

But it doesn't work.
I've had a look at this too: https://github.com/ohmybash/oh-my-bash/blob/master/themes/agnoster/agnoster.theme.sh#L156-L178
but I'm a bit lost.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by giving it a go one more time. I had to add one function by element I want to display, so I created a function to display time, and another to display history line, with the colors I want.

```
# Display history line
prompt_historyline(){
    prompt_segment yellow white ' \! '
}


# Display time
prompt_time() {
  prompt_segment orange white ' [\A] '
}
```

And my prompt_context function :

```
prompt_context() {
    local user=`whoami`

    if [[ $user == $DEFAULT_USER || $user != $DEFAULT_USER || -n $SSH_CLIENT ]]; then
            # green is the color of background
            # white is the color of foreground          
            
        prompt_segment green white " $user@\h "        
    fi
}
```

and then I added my two news functions to the main function (the builder of the main prompt):

```
build_prompt() {
[[ ! -z ${AG_EMACS_DIR+x} ]] && prompt_emacsdir
prompt_status
prompt_historyline
prompt_time
#[[ -z ${AG_NO_HIST+x} ]] && prompt_histdt
[[ -z ${AG_NO_CONTEXT+x} ]] && prompt_context
prompt_virtualenv
prompt_dir
prompt_git
prompt_end

}
```

Here is the result:

[image]